# Infinite scroll by just scrolling down the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

The below script is for data that gets fired for every click, but i want the data that get fired when the user scrolls down the page
CODE:

```
            $(document).ready(function(){
            $(document).on("click",'.getmore', function( event ){
                var last_id = $(this).attr('id');   
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url : 'http://localhost/tech1/services/getmore.php',    
                    data: 'last_id='+last_id,
                    beforeSend: function(){
                        $('.getmore').html('<img src="../images/loader.gif" alt="Loading..." />');  
                    },
                    success: function(data){
                        $('.getmore').remove();
                        $('#comments').append(data);
                    }
                });
            }); 
        });
```

Edit-Available code:

```
function infiniteAjaxCall(getmore){  //<---pass id in the param
   $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost/tech1/services/getmore.php',
    data: 'last_id=' + getmore})  //<-----and use it here


     $(document).ready(function () 
     {
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $(document).on("click", '.getmore', function (event) {
       var last_id = $(this).attr('id');
       infiniteAjaxCall(last_id);
        });

      $(window).on('scroll', function()
         {
         if($(document).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height())
  {
          $('.getmore').click();
  }
       });
           })} )}
```

here is the available code but couldn't fix the issue.

Comment: You want to look at the `$(window).scroll` event and compare `$(window).scrollTop()` to your elements. *which I see Jai has already provided details of*.

Comment: Read a tutorial. http://bit.ly/1i4DRvn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try adding this:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
   $(document).on("click", '.getmore', function (event) {
     var last_id = $(this).attr('id');
     $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost/tech1/services/getmore.php',
        data: 'last_id=' + last_id,
        beforeSend: function () {
            $('.getmore').html('<img src="../images/loader.gif" alt="Loading..." />');
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $('.getmore').remove();
            $('#comments').append(data);
        }
    });
  });

  $(window).on('scroll', function(){
      if($(document).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
          $('.getmore').click();   //^^^^^^^^update the if condition^^^^^^^^---
      }
  });

});
```

Another way i can suggest is this:

make a global function :

```
function infiniteAjaxCall(id){  //<---pass id in the param
       $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost/tech1/services/getmore.php',
        data: 'last_id=' + id,  //<-----and use it here
}
```

then your button click:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
   $(document).on("click", '.getmore', function (event) {
     var last_id = $(this).attr('id');
     infiniteAjaxCall(last_id);
  });

  $(window).on('scroll', function(){
      if($(document).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
          var last_id = $('.getmore').attr('id');
          infiniteAjaxCall(last_id);
          // or this
          // $('.getmore').click(); // you can try commenting out first two lines above.
      }
  });

});
```

Comment: You might want to trigger this before you reach the actual page bottom, but +1 for getting a sensible answer in so quick.

Comment: @Jai its still wants me to click the event to fire the data.

Comment: Don't trigger multiple loads if you can avoid it. Moving mouse up and down at page bottom will keep triggering simultaneous loads (until one completes and replaces the content).

Comment: @Jai i can find an error in console which says missing ) after argument list. I am new to scriptng lang, dont mind to ask such silly.

Comment: @Fastnto update the if condition as this `if($(document).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){`

Comment: and if this is the issue then you can see the linenumber in the console and you can click on the link that will show you the error source code at a specific line.

Comment: @Jai which id i need to pass for that params. btw thanks for ur continues help.

Comment: `$(this).attr('id');` the clicked button's id.

Comment: or try replacing the function in the scroll function with this: `$('.getmore').click();`.

Comment: `function infiniteAjaxCall(getmore){  
       $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost/tech1/services/getmore.php',
        data: 'last_id=' + 'getmore',})` is this completely fine?? its not firing the data.

Comment: `'getmore'` remove the quotes.

Comment: @Jai still it doesnt firing the data after removing quotes.

Comment: `data: 'last_id=' + '.getmore'` change to this: `data: 'last_id=' + getmore`

Comment: @Jai yes i did that, still not firing the data,.

Comment: @Jai Your 1st or above answer seems like firing the data but not displaying the data, its firing in console.

Comment: @Jai Its firing the same data.